# GPS location in my app

Tags: java, android

Im having trouble passing the current location to my LatLng variable to show on my google map. Im not sure how to pass the value from my override statement in my location listener method. Im trying to implement an application that simply gets the GPS coordinates and places a marker on the map.

```
    @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //obtain location
    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng appoint = new LatLng(lat,lng);
            return appoint;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }
    };

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    double lat = 34.014783;
    double lng = -84.571381;

    // Add a marker in Appoint from database and move the camera
    LatLng appoint = new LatLng(lat,lng);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(appoint).title("Where the wild gays are"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(appoint));`
```

Comment: try to create method  and pass lat and long to that method from your onlocationchanged method

Answer (score 0):

Well, `onLocationChanged` doesn't return anything `void` so you cannot return the `LatLng` object, but you can add the `marker` to the `mMap` object (as long as it is not null).

E.g.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng appoint = new LatLng(lat,lng);
        if(mMap != null) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(appoint).title("Where the wild gays are"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(appoint));
        }
    }
```